# Find radius of convergence for $\sum c_n z^n$ where $c_{2k} = 2^k, c_{2k-1} \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k^2}$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Find radius of convergence for $\sum c_n z^n$ where $c_{2k} = 2^k, c_{2k-1} \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k^2}$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$

Problem from my book I am attempting to do. Here is my approach.

Lets look at the coefficients separately by analyzing the n-th root.

First, $\limsup |2^k|^\frac{1}{k} = 2$.

Second, $\limsup \left |\left( \frac{k+1}{k} \right )^{k^2} \right|^{1/k} = \limsup \left( \frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k}$.

We have $$\overline \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k} = e $$

I assume, we take the smaller radius of convergence, so the whole series converges for $|z| < \frac{1}{e}$. Not really sure if this appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: For your second, $k^2/k=k$, not $1/k$.

Comment: Does $c_{2k}=k^2$ or $2^k$?

Comment: $2^k$! Let me fix this up.

Comment: There is a result which says that if $R$ is the radius of convergence of the taylor series $\sum c_nz^n$, then $$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{c_n}\ ,$$
so you're definitely on the right track. 

A side note: $\limsup\big|\big(1+\frac{1}{k}\big)^{k^2}\big|^{1/k}=\limsup\big|\big(1+\frac{1}{k}\big)^{k}\big|$. This limit is not 1. It's a very famous limit!

Comment: @EdMo38 Made a silly mistake with the powers. Think I fixed it up!

Comment: But now we have to be careful: $$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{c_n}=\text{the larger of }\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[2k]{2^k}\text{ or }\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[2k-1]{(1+1/k)^{k^2}}\ ,$$
which may complicate things...